# Reverse color of base64 pdf in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I have a random pdf encoded to base64, is there any way I can programmatically switch its colors to the negative form? (Ex. white to black, red to blue, etc)

Comment: _"is there any way...?"_ - yes. Decode the Base64 string; unpack the PDF and decompress the contents; parse the result to identify style elements, images, etc; apply suitable algorithms to transform the document; pack and compress the updated elements into a new PDF; Base64 encode it. Simple. Which bit do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes: using PdfJS you can draw the PDF to a canvas, it's not to hard.
then with the canvas you can invert the colors, but you will have an image as a result and not a PDF. You can show that image in your HTML or download it.